# HTML1121: Codepage unicode is not allowed, only codepage utf-8 is allowed

Tags: javascript, windows, html, windows-8, character-encoding

I see this error in Visual Studio 2012 as I'm trying to get my HTML5 app running inside a native Windows 8 app:

*HTML1121: Codepage unicode is not allowed, only codepage utf-8 is allowed.*

Clearly it's a character encoding issue, but I'm not familiar with the differences between unicode and UTF-8. Can anyone shed some light on this?

Comment: Unicode is the standard, covering many different topics that relate to character handling. UTF-8 is *one possible* encoding defined as part of the Unicode standard.

Comment: Ok... but any idea what specifically might throw an error like that? I'm trying to look at my HTML encoded characters to see if they could be the source.

Comment: Digging a bit deeper, I see that a line "document.designMode = 'on';" seems to throw this error...

Answer (score 0):

If you are bringing files into your project from outside VS, use VS and the ***Save filename As*** feature and select the ***Save With Encoding*** from the ***Save*** dropdown.  Choose UTF-8 Encoding.  This will normally solve the problem you are experiencing.

All JavaScript files (files with a .js extension) included in the app package are converted into bytecode that the JavaScript engine can consume directly. This requires UTF-8 encoding, IIRC.

Comment: I don't think this is the issue. I only see the error when I set the "designMode" of an IFRAME which is created dynamically by JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

When Microsoft says `Unicode` they generally mean UTF-16:

> ... UTF-16 (wide character) encoding, which is the most common encoding of Unicode and the one used for native Unicode encoding on Windows operating systems.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd374081(v=vs.85).aspx

The designMode flag ends up forcing the browser to fall back to UTF-16, whereas windows 8 expects UTF-8 (that decision to migrate to UTF-8 is relatively recent).  Your best option is to keep designMode off and rework the page

Answer (score -1):

Unicode is a standard. It assigns characters to abstract code points. But there's more, most of the work is actually towards creating properties for those code points as well as defining relationships between them.

For example, the character `A` (LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A) is assigned to code point `U+0041`. Properties defined for this code point include for example that its General Category is `Letter, Uppercase` and that it's written from left-to-right. It has a relationship with the code point `U+0061`, in that `U+0061` is its lowercase mapping. So that's Unicode.

There are **U**nicode **T**ransformation **F**ormats for mapping these abstract code points to actual concrete bytes in a computer. And this is what is relevant when specifiying encoding, "code page" or "charset". You should use UTF-8.

Also, "Unicode" can actually refer to the encoding UTF-16LE in some Microsoft contexts.

Comment: So the app itself is written using HTML and JavaScript - and the HTML page has UTF-8 declared in its meta tags. I only see this error when changing the "designMode" of a child IFRAME at runtime... so it's just all very confusing.